# Calculate U-SQL Percentage

Tags: u-sql

I am trying to calculate Deployment percentage.  but my CASE statement is returning a whole number.

Example: 
  Deployment = 133
  Licensing = 930

Utilization should == 14%

However, returns 0

Here is the table schema for utilization:

```
,[Deployment (%)] float?
```

Here is how I calculate utilization:

```
        (summary.[Deployments] == 0 OR summary.[Licensing] == 0) ? 0 :
            (summary.[Deployments] / summary.[[Licensing]) AS [Deployment (%)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to add (decimal) on the dividend

```
    (summary.[Deployments] == 0 OR summary.[Licensing] == 0) ? 0 :
        ((decimal)summary.[Deployments] / summary.[[Licensing]) AS [Deployment (%)]
```

Comment: Since you were able to answer your own question, can you please mark it as the answer? :)